# ast.literal_eval(None) versus ast.literal_eval('None')

Tags: python-2.7

From the ast docs I can get the following information:

Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

From this it seems that ast.literal_eval(None) should work.

However in python 2.7 I get ValueError: malformed string when I try do ast.literal_eval(None).
This does not happen if I do ast.literal_eval('None').

Can anyone explain why? I have looked at the other questions on StackOverflow about ast.literaleval and malformed string but none of them address this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`None` is neither a string nor an [expression node](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#node-classes), therefore there is no reason to believe that it is valid argument for `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, that helped me realise where I went wrong. I misread the documentation. Specifically I missed the piece that says it must be a string or a node. Thank you for helping out and gently pointing out the rather obvious answer.